# Find value of a nested array dynamically based on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am working on nested array and try to find a value inside the nested array based on condition. The API returns the data in the format shown below.

```js
data=
  {
    "ch_Id": "1234",
    "title": "Title",
    "status": 4,
    "options": [
      {
        "ch_message": "ABC broad casting ",
        "ch_title": "ABC",
        "referenceType": "Internal"
      }
    ],
    "stage": "active"
  }
]
```

I am working on loading data dynamically into a div based on a condition. So based on a condition, sometimes the fieldname is ch-Id, and other times it is options[0].ch_message. So, how do I dynamically retrieve the value of fieldname whatever is coming from the input and bind it to the div?

For ch_Id, I can get the value using data[ch_Id], but if I give data[options[0].ch_message], I get undefined.

```js
displayValue: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    this.fieldName= resultData[fieldName] ;// this can be ch_Id or options[0].ch_message

        // Filter the array value based on fieldName
        const filteredData = Object.entries(this.data).filter(([key, value]) => key === this.fieldName)
        this.displayValue = filteredData[0][1]
        console.log('this.displayValue',this.displayValue);
    }
```

Comment: use `data['options'][0]['ch_message']`

Comment: `data['options'][0].ch_message` exists, but `data['options[0].ch_message']` - doesn't, see the difference? Check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path

Comment: const deep_value = (obj, path) => 
path
    .replace(/\[|\]\.?/g, '.')
    .split('.')
    .filter(s => s)
    .reduce((acc, val) => acc && acc[val], obj);

This code from the shared link worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code mentioned in the below link by Nick Grealy worked for me.

[Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

```js
const deep_value = (obj, path) => 
path
    .replace(/\[|\]\.?/g, '.')
    .split('.')
    .filter(s => s)
    .reduce((acc, val) => acc && acc[val], obj);


console.log(deep_value(someObject, "part1.name"));               
console.log(deep_value(someObject, "pa[rt3[0].name"));
```